# Why does heroku think my repo is up to date even after I force push a older commit?

Tags: git, heroku

If I force push a commit that is older than head, it works. If I then try to push head, I'm told everything is up to date. Why? Is this a general git issue, or unique to heroku? Does the second command actually

```
# this works, as expected
git push heroku develop:master
...

# then, this doesn't work, as expected
git push heroku develop:master
Everything up-to-date

# then, pushing an older commit works, as expected
git push heroku a1b2c3d4:master
...

# then, this fails. why?!  :-(
git push heroku develop:master
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you push the old commit ever to Heroku? I would think you didn't because Heroku probably determines on the commit id if it has received the version or not. 
This hypothesis could be verified by the following steps:

```
1. git push heroku develop:master => our starting point
2. Change and commit => Rev A
3. Change and commit => Rev B
4. git push heroku develop:master => Rev B known to Heroku
5. Change and commit => Rev C
6. git push heroku develop:master => Rev C known to Heroku
7. git push heroku Rev A:master => this should work as unknown to Heroku
8. git push heroku Rev B:master => this should not work as known to Heroku
9. git push heroku develop:master => we know this doesn't work
```

Anyway, you can roll back and forth with
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history
and
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

Comment: Could you elaborate on the ideas in your first paragraph, or give me a link to something I can read? Thanks!

Comment: I added a proposal outlining my idea and possible way to verify it. If you run it would be great if you can add it as an additional answer.